# call same function on different non-related objects?

Tags: .net, function, object, c++-cli

I have a set of objects, all of a different type, lets say

```
CTree^  oTree;
CCar^   oCar;
CHouse^ oHouse;
```

All classes of these objects have the same function

```
static EnumResult SetValueDebug (EnumPID i_enPID, Object^ i_Object);
```

where EnumResult and EnumPID ("parameter ID") are defined in each class.

My idea was to create something like

```
Object^ oResult;
array<Object^>^ ao = gcnew array<Object^>{oTree, oCar, oHouse};
for (int iCnt = 0; iCnt < ao->Length; iCnt++)
  oResult = ao[iCnt]->SetValueDebug (ao[iCnt]->EnumPID::Param1, DefaultValue);
  // call it on the real object although it's a static function, because there is
  //  no dynamic_cast<ao[iCnt]->GetType>(ao[iCnt]) ::SetValueDebug ( ...
```

but I don't know how.

I thought of using inheritance:

```
ref class CSuperior
{
public:
  enum class EnumResult { ... };
  enum class EnumPID { ... };
  static EnumResult SetValueDebug (EnumPID i_enPID, Object^ i_Object)
  {
    m_aoValue[(int)i_enPID] = i_Object
  };
protected:
  array<Object^>^ m_aObject;
  ...
}
```

where m_aObject can be accessed from the inheriting class. Would this work?

But inheritance likely fails because I am already inheriting some classes from others.
Using an interface fails here, too, afaik.

Is there any chance to realise something like described above?

Comment: If the objects are not related but you know for sure that they have that specific method, you can call it using reflection, by string method name

Comment: Thanks, I will keep that in mind for future use. I am now thinking again of using inheritance, as I found other positive effects that a superior class will have in my application. Each class will now inherit from that superior one, and the other classes that already do inherit will inherit the superior class via their base class. So everything should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Why should an interface fail?

```
enum class EnumResult { ... };
enum class EnumPID { ... };

ref interface ISuperior
{
public:
  EnumResult SetValueDebug (EnumPID i_enPID, Object^ i_Object);
}
```

Then each class can implement this interface...

Comment: Up to now, EnumResult and EnumClass are part of each ref class. Each class has different function results and parameter IDs, so I don't want to make these enums 'global'.

Comment: If there is no common sence, you have almost no way... of course, you can also have a intface for "result" and the enums... which makes it more complex....